# Javascript - Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters time complexity?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I implemented the Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters algorithm in Javascript.

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    if(!s || s.length === 0)    return 0;
    
    let max = 0;
    let set = new Set();
    
    for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        if(!set.has(s[i])) {
            set.add(s[i]);
            max = Math.max(max, set.size);
        } else {
            set.clear();
            let c = s[i];
            i = i-1;
            while(i > 0 && s[i] !== c)
                i--;
            
        }
    }
    
    return Math.max(max, set.size);
};
```

Does it run in O(N)? I'm not sure because I have the `while` loop inside my `for` loop

Comment: I think it's O(n2) in this case, here are lot of ways to do that https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-of-the-longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

Comment: However the while loop will always be limited to the be less than the for loop, so why is it O(n2)?